# JTextFields--unable to edit,input text

Tags: java, swing, jframe, focus, jtextfield

I have two `JTextFields` that cannot be `edited/clicked` on unless I click outside the current `JFrame` window. I have tried to `setEditable`, `setEnabled`, `requestFocus()`, etc to true but all do not work. Any suggestions?

I do not know how to replicate the issue, but I believe it has to do with re-getting`JFrame` focus.

Comment: The only way to edit/be able to click on the JTextFields is to click on a different application/outside the JFrame and reclicking on the JFrame

Comment: Seeing your code may help with knowing what your issue is :)

Comment: Need to see the code that leads to this particular situation. Provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem.